# Why fontspec breaks extarrows package

Tags: xetex, fontspec

Why

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
$$Q\xLongrightarrow{\text{Maximum}} P$$
\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image]

and how can you fix this?

## More Details

With

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{palatino}
\begin{document}
$$Q\xLongrightarrow{Maximum} P$$
\end{document}
```

there are no palatino font. It seems to be a `fontspec` bug then.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided

Comment: @Thérèse: What about it should concern me?

Comment: It hasn’t enough features for testing anything sophisticated.  And your “More Details” section loads an obsolete package (`palatino`), and does not load `fontspec`, but concludes to a `fontspec` bug.

Comment: @Thérèse: I do not need many features. Please try `minimal` class with `fontspec` and without it and it should demonstrate my point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the `no-math` option to `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
$Q\xLongrightarrow{\text{Maximum}} P$
\end{document}
```

But the result is disputable, as Computer Modern math fonts don't combine well with Times.

[image]

What happens without the `no-math` option is that the upright math family (family 0) is changed to use the normal text font; the equals sign is taken from math family 0, so it doesn't combine with the double arrow taken from Computer Modern Math Symbols.

Should you want to use TeX Gyre Termes Math along with Times New Roman for the text font, some workarounds are necessary, since the developers didn't provide for the double arrows to combine with the equals sign.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[
  range={`=,\Longrightarrow,\Rightarrow,\Longleftarrow,\Leftarrow}
]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}

$Q\xLongrightarrow{\text{Maximum}} P$

$Q\xLongleftarrow{\text{Maximum}} P$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A complete workaround covering also extendable single arrows.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[
  range={
    `=,\Longrightarrow,\Rightarrow,\Longleftarrow,\Leftarrow,
    \harrowextender,\longrightarrow,\rightarrow,\longleftarrow,\leftarrow
  }
]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\renewcommand{\relbar}{\mathrel{\harrowextender}}

\begin{document}
$Q\xlongrightarrow{\text{Maximum}} P$

$Q\xlongleftarrow{\text{Maximum}} P$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a new change to `fontspec`? I know that `no-math` option existed for a long time but a user reported that thid did not happen until he updated his TeXLive today.

Comment: @user56799 That user probably had something like TeX Live 2009 or earlier.

Comment: Thanks. I got what has changed. I will fix it in my package and it should fix it.

Comment: Adding the `no-math` option works in this case, but it wouldn't appear to be a general solution. For instance, if `TeX Gyre Termes` is loaded as the text font and `TeX Gyre Termes Math` as the math font, one gets an ugly arrow head even if `no-math` is specified for `fontspec`. Now this may have more to do with the Texgyre Termes fonts than with the way `fontspec` is loaded, but it's still worth keeping in mind.

Comment: @Mico Unfortunately, the developers of TeX Gyre Termes made the double arrows not combining with the equal sign. The same is for TeX Gyre Pagella Math. Conversely, XITS, Asana and Lucida Bright are good. Unicode has a single arrow extender character, none for double arrows.

Comment: @egreg -- the unicode single-arrow extender is "grandfathered"; my understanding is that this means other characters of the same general category "will not be added".  i will take this up again with my contacts on the committee, this time with the added incentive that it's needed for mathjax.  (thus far, all my requests of this nature have been met with "that's the job of the composition software.")

Comment: @barbarabeeton Possibly code points for “extendable arrows” might be added. The extensions might be similar to the ones for wide accents. In any case, extendable arrows *are* widely used.

Answer (score 6):

You need to load a math font that's compatible with the chosen text font. (A give-away that you're using Computer Modern is contained in the shapes of the letters `P` and `Q`.) I suggest you load the package `unicode-math` and set `\setmathfont{XITS Math}`.

If you choose this route, I would also recommend you set `XITS` (a Times Roman clone) as the main text font.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
\[Q\xLongrightarrow{\text{Maximum}} P\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am told this did not happen with older versions of fontspec. Any ideas?

Comment: @user56799 - I'm afraid I have no particular knowledge of the differences between the various vintages of `fontspec`. For all I know, the problem you've encountered may not even be caused by `fontspec` itself.

Comment: I think textfont should have nothing to do with this. Please see my edited question. You can try any other only text font package and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Change the order of the packages:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\[ Q\xLongrightarrow{\text{Maximum}} P \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution isn't robust to the addition of the loading of arbitrary math fonts. E.g., if one switches from `Times New Roman` to `TeX Gyre Termes` (another `Times Roman` clone) and adds the instructions `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}`, one either gets a bad arrow if `extarrows` is loaded *before* `unicode-math` or an error message if it's loaded afterwards.

Comment: sure, with _another_ math font you have to use the old order but loading `unicode-math`. But then it also works.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to make a different point: if `TeX Gyre Termes` and `TeX Gyre Termes Math` are loaded, then `\xLongrightarrow` will create an ugly result *irrespective* of the loading order. Changing the loading order thus isn't a general solution.

Comment: Why should someone load a math font like `TeX Gyre Termes Math` which has at this time a lot of missing charcters?? However, a simple `\setmathfont[range=\Longrightarrow]{XITS Math}` will do.