# Arrow length in LuaTeX in combination with the unicode-math package

Tags: luatex, arrows, unicode-math

I have a probably rather simple question: Is it possible to use the `unicode-math` package within LuaLaTeX such that arrows stretch when writing some longer expression above or below it?

For example the following code with the package `unicode-math` loaded doesn't produce stretched arrows and the text over the arrow is much longer than the arrow itself:

```
% TeX engine: LuaLaTeX   
% TeX Live 2014   
% TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath,
            unicode-math}

\begin{document}

$a \xrightarrow{b \to \infty} c$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd consider this a bug both in `unicode-math`, which should provide a good equivalent of `\std@minus` when `amsmath` is loaded and of Latin Modern Math, that doesn't provide a glyph for `\harrowextender` (U+23AF HORIZONTAL LINE EXTENSION). See the related question [Why fontspec breaks extarrows package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191265/why-fontspec-breaks-extarrows-package)

For your problem, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,unicode-math}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\Umathcharnumdef\std@minus\Umathcodenum`- }% \std@minus is minus
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \xrightarrow{b \to \infty} c$

\end{document}
```

A better workaround should use `\harrowextender` when available:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,unicode-math}
%\setmathfont{Asana Math} % if uncommented, \harrowextender would be used

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \check@mathfonts
  \iffontchar\textfont\tw@\string"23AF
    \renewcommand{\relbar}{\mathrel\harrowextender}%
  \else
    \Umathcharnumdef\std@minus\Umathcodenum`-
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \xrightarrow{b \to \infty} c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second code uses `\check@mathfonts` to ensure fonts are associated to the math families (LaTeX normally doesn't do this until the first formula is being typeset in order to avoid using up math families that couldn't be unused in the document).

With `unicode-math`, the math font defined by `\setmathfont` is associated to math family 2, so we check whether the character corresponding to `\harrowextender` exists in the font (see the e-TeX manual, `texdoc etex` for `\iffontchar`). If the character exists, we redefine `\relbar` to be that symbol as math relation. Otherwise, we resort to using a minus sign, under the name `\std@minus` that's used by `amsmath` in this context.

What happens without the code is that `\std@minus` becomes “choose character 0 in math family 2“, which is correct for the traditional TeX math fonts, but is not true any more for `unicode-math`. So in this case we redefine `\std@minus` to be a math char having the same code as the minus sign (see the XeTeX manual, `texdoc xetex`, for more information about `\Umath...` commands).

Comment: Thank you very much! It works for me now. Do you know where I can find a documentation on the LaTeX-code you used?

Comment: @bfc I added some notes.

Comment: Any possibility to report that problem to LM Math? Can't find any issue tracker or alike.

Comment: I think only email to the TeX Gyre team, but I'm not sure it can have any effect.