# Vertical spacing between arrow and caption with unicode-math

Tags: spacing, arrows, unicode-math

When using `unicode-math` and arrow captions (most prominently with `extarrows`), the vertical spacing between the arrows and the text increases a lot:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,extarrows}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
   \[ \xLongrightarrow{\text{This is a test}} \]
\end{document}
```

Without `unicode-math` the result is

[image: small spacing];

however, with `unicode-math`, the result becomes

[image].

This holds true for all the extensible arrows; however, the spacing in `\xlongequals` remains fine.

By default, these examples all use Latin Modern, so the extension character fits to the arrow head unlike in [some other fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191265/why-fontspec-breaks-extarrows-package/191276). Is this perhaps a `unicode-math` bug or is the position information in the OTF fonts wrong, which causes such a misalign? (Basically, the problem is also there for `\xrightarrow`, so it does not seem to be a problem of `extarrows` in particular.)

The result is the same both in LuaLaTex and XeLaTeX.